# how to get a count(*) for number of records updated

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

i am updating a sql server 2008 database using c# like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    faxstatus = row.ItemArray[5].ToString().Contains("0000") ? "Faxed" : "Error";

    query = 
        @"update FileLog set
        FaxStatus=" + "'" + faxstatus + "'," +
        "FaxedPageCount=" + "'" + row.ItemArray[1] + "'," +
        "dtFaxed=" + "'" + row.ItemArray[2] + "'," +
        "BiscomCode=" + "'" + row.ItemArray[5] + "', " +
        "RetryCount=" + "'" + row.ItemArray[4] + "' " +
        "where CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), JobID) =" + "'" + row.ItemArray[3] + "'" +
        " and FaxStatus<>'Faxed'";

    command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    NumberOfRecordsUpdated++;

}
```

i would like to know whether it is possible to return how many records were updated?

Comment: This code leaks, you need to `Dispose` the `SqlCommand` or (better) wrap it in a `using` stamtent.

Comment: I have to say that's a very dirty way to update the database.  I really hope you don't have any "'" characters in your data!  As a minimum you should be using parameters.

Comment: @Joel: Parameterised statements forever!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capture and use the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` to an integer. That method returns the number of records affected by the operation.

See [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

That being said, how much do you trust your datasource? Enough to bet your data integrity on it? I'd be remissed if I didn't implore you to explore parameterized queries. A `using` statement would also be warranted so that your disposable resources (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, etc.) are properly dealt with.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Use `ExecuteNonQuery`'s return value. :-)

Quoting [`ExecuteNonQuery`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.

Answer (score 3):

Refering to [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) :

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The number of rows affected.

Answer (score 3):

Append `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` to your statement and use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNoneQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) .